# Comparing previous value and next value in Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, loops, zip, series

I have a pandas dataframe with OHCL data, 
I would like to compare every value in the Low series with the previous value and the next value in that series.

```
2018-08-31    1.15839
2018-08-30    1.16411
2018-08-29    1.16511
2018-08-28    1.16618
2018-08-27    1.15938
2018-08-24    1.15340
```

If the value is less than the previous value and less than the next value in the series, I would like to return the value in a **new series** (df.Low) to True for that index, else to False.

Another possibility is to retreive the value where the condition is true but with the index attached to it.

I tried with zip and this worked, but I lost the index doing this.

```
Lows = []
Highs = []

for x,y,z in zip(df.Low_Price[::],df.Low_Price[1::],df.Low_Price[2::]):
    if x > y < z:
        Low = np.around(y, decimals=5)
        Lows.append(Low)

for x,y,z in zip(df.High_Price[::],df.High_Price[1::],df.High_Price[2::]):
    if x < y > z:
        High = np.around(y, decimals=5)
        Highs.append(High)
```

Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, you are introducing look-ahead bias (unless 'next value' is backwards looking, i.e. T-2?).  Also, what is your expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to retreive all possible lows and highs, this is the first step to a zig zag indicator. The next step to identify a new low will be if the next upmove touches the 38.2 fibonacci retracement and price doesn't cross the previous low.

This step is to find possible candidates for highs and lows where the previous and the next candle isn't higher (for the highs) and lower (for the lows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try of shifting the dataframe values to next and previous to check conditions

considered dataframe

```
        0        1
0   2018-08-31  1.15839
1   2018-08-30  1.16411
2   2018-08-29  1.16511
3   2018-08-28  1.16618
4   2018-08-27  1.15938
5   2018-08-24  1.15340


[(df[1].ge(df[1].shift())) & df[1].le(df[1].shift(-1))]
```

Out:

```
[0    False
 1     True
 2     True
 3    False
 4    False
 5    False
 Name: 1, dtype: bool]
```

if your intention is to just check low value of whole column, you can use

```
df[1].min()
```

Out:

```
1.1534
```

Answer (score 2):

Using shift:

For low,

```
df[(df['a'].lt(df['a'].shift(-1))) & df['a'].lt(df['a'].shift(1))]
```

For high,

```
df[(df['a'].gt(df['a'].shift(-1))) & df['a'].gt(df['a'].shift(1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to your solution with zip

```
Lows = []
Highs = []

for i,x,y,z in zip(df.index[1::], df.Low_Price[::],df.Low_Price[1::],df.Low_Price[2::]):
    if x > y < z:
        Low = np.around(y, decimals=5)
        Lows.append([i, Low])

for i,x,y,z in zip(df.index[1::],df.High_Price[::],df.High_Price[1::],df.High_Price[2::]):
    if x < y > z:
        High = np.around(y, decimals=5)
        Highs.append([i, High])
```